# How to import Oracle sql file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I have a `.sql` file from Oracle which contains create table/index statements and a lot of insert statements(around 1M insert).

I can manually modify the create table/index part(not too much), but for the insert part there are some Oracle functions like to_date.

I know MySql has a similar function STR_TO_DATE but the usage of the parameter is different.

I can connect to MySQL, but the .sql file is the only thing I got from Oracle.

Is there any way I can import this Oracle .sql file into MySQL?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, you certainly can't execute oracle-specific sql against a non-oracle database.  You will have to edit the file.  I'd think some well-considered search-and-replace would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the above job can be done by manually editing the script appropriately however there are products available which can be of use. Refer to the [link](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql#:%7E:text=SQLines%20SQL%20Converter%20tool%20allows,database%20use%20SQLines%20Data%20tool.) for more information on one such product.

P.S. I am not affiliated in any way to the product

Comment: I think the best way if manually editing the SQL file. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention about insert script basically i think you will be inserting data for this you can use any ETL tool, like open source tool like Pentaho data integrator, pretty simple to do, just search table to table transformation from different database connection on youtube to learn you should be able to connect to both mysql and oracle database else this wont help, but all the table structures you should create manually in the source database for data - you can just load it using ETL, no need to edit for every single line of insert if its more than 100 may be its very painful thing to do.